# Animation in a single file

Tags: android, android-animation

I have the following animation for a button, for another button I need to a change few parameters. How do I do that in the same xml file. The following code is present in res/anim directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:fromXDelta="300%" android:toXDelta="0%" android:fromYDelta="300%"
android:toYDelta="0%" android:duration="1000" android:zAdjustment="bottom" />
```

Comment: Copying it might be the easiest thing to do, you usually end up changing everything at the end anyway :)

Comment: Copy it to a new xml file you mean? Cant I make some changes in the same file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution although cumbersome at first is to make each animation separate, in its own file.  It may feel like duplicate code but after a while you will see that when you're changing settings in different place just to get the right effect then you'll be glad you didn't tie the two widget animations together.